# Finding out when does a call start ringing

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I have an android app from which I can start calls. Id like to know if it is possible to know when does the actual ringing start. Sth like TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK is not enough, as its triggered already as i start dialing, few secs before the ringing I want starts. Thanks

Comment: we have a `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` this state occur when phone start ringing when any call appear?

Comment: I want to know when does the ringing start at outgoing calls, not when Im being called.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the past, and it get invoked as soon as I see Ringing...

Hope this helps

http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/62.html

Comment: I need something to invoke at ringing when I call someone, not when I am called by someone.